# Mos amplifier output characteristics

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

[image]

I have a problem in the first region where M1 and M2 are in saturation.If both the NMOS are in saturation,how can the Vout be VDD.Shouldn't Vout be close to 0V as the pulldown current is much greater than the pullup current?Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Saturation is not the same as "a lot of current". A transistor with a small enough \$v_{GS}\$ can be in saturation and still conduct *very little* current.

The situation is something close to this:

[image: IDS vs VOUT]

The output voltage is set by looking at the intersection of the two graphs, because the current \$i_{DS}\$ has to flow through *all* transistors.

M1 and M2 have a small \$v_{GS}\$ and a large \$v_{DS}\$, so they are in saturation. The small \$v_{GS}\$ means that - even though it is in saturation - the transistor doesn't pass much current. In comparison, the large \$v_{GS}\$ of M3 will make it possible to produce higher currents so it will need a smaller \$v_{DS}\$ to produce the same current as M1/M2.

Comment: Can u explain how do we deal with these type of circuits?While plotting Vout vs Vin how do we look into all these factors and determine vout?

Comment: The most robust way is by using KCL in your head: current in = current out. Then you ask yourself at what voltage that law is satisfied. After you gain some experience you can usually simplify the circuit, and part of the analysis becomes "automatic".

Comment: For example, for low \$v_{GS}\$, M1&M2 are *barely on*, so they ask less current. M3 has a large \$v_{GS}\$ so it can source *a lot of current*. So the balance in the output node is in favor of the PMOS, causing the output voltage to be pulled **up**.

Comment: When i start calibrating I see when Vin=0 all the 3 MOS are on.Then how can i determine what will be the value of Vout in this case?

Comment: It will be of great help if you can give some guidelines for solving this particular numerical.Then maybe i will be able to solve related problems.Thank you.

Comment: I advise *against* solving this numerically. It quickly gets too complex. I suggest using simple rules to determine which currents are small and/or large. Thinking in terms of "on" and "off" will quickly get you into trouble. Think in broad terms using \$v_{GS}\$/\$v_{DS}\$ and how that relates to transistor current. If \$V_{in}=0\$, then M3 has a large \$v_{GS}\$ so its IV curve will be higher like in the graph.

Comment: Sir you have already given too much valuable insight in this problem,but if i may request you,is there any particular text from where i can develop these intuitions like for a given input i am asked about the output in a specific point of the circuit?

Comment: The most tried and best way I know of is **experience**. Trying to understand as many CMOS circuits as you can - like you are doing now - and verifying your hypothesis (eg. via a teacher or visual inspection using a simulator). CMOS is a beast in that regard (ie. it has a steep learning curve).

Comment: I guess for circuits like the one i have mentioned here,as there are so many variables i should avoid mathematical analysis and go for a rather approximate analysis based upon Vgs and Vds as you have suggested earlier.